# Reasonable Limits (alarm) for sensor temperature (lm-sensors)

Tags: cpu, temperature, hardware-detection, sensors, lm-sensors

Using `sensors` command (package `lm-sensors`) one finds out values (mainly temperature).
I guess it is not useful at all, if one is not capable of estimating which values are critical?
How to find reasonable limits? I want to add them as alarm in `mate-sensors-applet`. Is this the same setting as defined directly by sensors program using sensors.conf ([libsensors configuration file](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-sensors.conf/))?

Attached my output of sensors program:

```
$ sensors
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     2800 RPM
temp1:        +60.0°C  

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.22 V  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +60.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +59.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +56.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:         N/A  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.10 V)
temp1:            N/A  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +60.0°C  (crit = +108.0°C)
```

How to determine which are critical?

Comment: `crit =` looks like critical to me... Or do you mean, which sensors specifically should you add the alarm(s) for?

Comment: What limits should be set? I know that these are some default limits, but the question remains which limits for which hardware/sensors?

Comment: That's really up to you. If I were you, I'd step down say 10% for each `crit` value and set that as my alarm level. No answer on here will tell you what to set, it's really personal preference. I've marked the question as opinion-based, for the stated reason.

Comment: It is not just an individual question since the hardware is dominated by physical laws and thus may crash if too hot, so it's legitimate to ask what these limits are.
What is a justifiable reason to use -10% for these values?
Which other methods might be applicable?

Comment: "personal preference".